# Why does couenne not quit after iterations show same result over and over?

Tags: python, pyomo

I have following code using `pyomo` in python:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

mymodel=ConcreteModel()    
var_x = Var([1,2], [0,1,2,3], domain=Reals)
var_y = Var([1,2], [0,1,2,3], domain=Reals)
var_z = Var([0,1,2,3], domain=Reals)
mymodel.q = var_x
mymodel.p = var_y
mymodel.u = var_z

express=(var_z[0] ** 2) + (var_y[1,0] * var_x[2,0]) + (var_y[2,0] * var_x[1,0])

cost_fn = Objective(expr=express)

mymodel.objective=cost_fn
sf = SolverFactory('couenne')
mymodel_results = sf.solve(mymodel)
print mymodel_results
```

The problem above should be fairly trivial - obvious to get optimal value just set all variables = 0.

But, the couenne solver chokes on it, and prints the same value over and over when solving.  When I print `mymodel_results` this is what I see inside of the Solver log:

```
ERROR: "[base]/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", 583, solve
    Solver log:
    Couenne 0.5.6 -- an Open-Source solver for Mixed Integer Nonlinear Optimization
    Mailing list: couenne@list.coin-or.org
    Instructions: http://www.coin-or.org/Couenne

    Couenne: new cutoff value 0.0000000000e+00 (0.005058 seconds)
    NLP0012I 
                  Num      Status      Obj             It       time                 Location
    NLP0014I             1         OPT 0        0 0.000188
    Loaded instance "/var/folders/4f/z25gj3_d29b45_2nx87p8rvr0000gn/T/tmpsL5BN4.pyomo.nl"
    Constraints:            0
    Variables:              5 (0 integer)
    Auxiliaries:            4 (0 integer)

    Coin0506I Presolve 0 (-5) rows, 0 (-9) columns and 0 (-12) elements
    Clp0000I Optimal - objective value -9.99e+12
    Clp0032I Optimal objective -9.99e+12 - 0 iterations time 0.002, Presolve 0.00
    Clp0000I Optimal - objective value -9.99e+12
    NLP Heuristic: NLP0014I             2         OPT 0        0 0.000229
    no solution.
    Clp0000I Optimal - objective value -9.99e+12
    Optimality Based BT: 0 improved bounds
    Probing: 7 improved bounds
    NLP Heuristic: no solution.
    Cbc0013I At root node, 0 cuts changed objective from -9.99e+12 to -9.99e+12 in 1 passes
    Cbc0014I Cut generator 0 (Couenne convexifier cuts) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 2 column cuts (2 active)
    Cbc0010I After 0 nodes, 1 on tree, 1e+50 best solution, best possible -1.7976931e+308 (0.00 seconds)
    Optimality Based BT: 1 improved bounds
    Cbc0010I After 100 nodes, 50 on tree, 1e+50 best solution, best possible -9.99e+12 (4.52 seconds)
    Cbc0010I After 200 nodes, 100 on tree, 1e+50 best solution, best possible -9.99e+12 (4.53 seconds)
```

....same thing forever....

```
    Cbc0010I After 16600 nodes, 105 on tree, 1e+50 best solution, best possible -9.99e+12 (8.51 seconds)
```

Why is it choking on easy problem?

I know there is a timeout feature [How to set Pyomo solver timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405642/how-to-set-pyomo-solver-timeout), but this problem is simple and should not need it.  also, problem is easily solved by ipopt, but couenne should handle it as well.

Comment: You should try to set the timeout using a solver specific option. I assume Couenne has a solver option for this, but you will have to refer to the Couenne documentation for this. Also, Ipopt is designed to provide only locally optimal solutions, so it takes a much different approach to solving a problem than Couenne.

Comment: Thanks what do you mena by "solver specific option"?

Comment: I mean that the option name (if it exists) might change depending on the solver. For instance, Ipopt has an option named "max_cpu_time" that enforces this. You would set it by adding it to the `.options` dictionary on the solver returned from `SolverFactory` (e.g., `sf.options['max_cpu_time'] = 10`). Couenne might use the same option name, if it has one, or something similar. I believe you can pass timelimit as a keyword to the `solve()` method, but it will just do something similar to hitting ctrl-c, which in most cases will just abruptly kill the solver.

Comment: Using a solver-specific option, like 'max_cpu_time', _might_ allow the solver to return the best feasible solution it has found so far.

Comment: What is the difference between `sf.options['max_cpu_time'] = 10` as you suggest, and your answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyomo-forum/WzP1YwGyunw) to use `opt.options[‘timelimit’] = 1` ?

Comment: The first one is a real option for Ipopt. The second one is a fake option name that I used to show how to set a command-line option using the options dictionary on a solver.

Comment: @makansij, did you ever find a solution? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: No, I didn't!  At least not a satisfactory one.  I ended up using ipopt instead.  Let me know if you solve it please!